# Retornar o valor a esquerda

Tags: sql, sql-server

bom dia.

Uma dúvida, como posso retornar os resultados de uma coluna que contenha apenas os valores a esquerda que iniciam com a palavra 'carro' por exemplo?
Estou usando o sql server.

Obrigado.

Comment: Não entendi a parte `"..apenas os valores a esquerda..."`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode usar o operador `like`:

```
SELECT * FROM EXEMPLO WHERE VALOR LIKE 'CARRO%'
```

O operador `%` é o coringa, você pode usar ele em qualquer posição. Por exemplo, se você quer ver se a palavra está no final do resultado você usaria `%carro`, se no meio do resultado usaria `%carro%` e assim por diante.

Comment: Show Diego, funcionou perfeito. Muito obrigado, abs.